# How to save each cloned div into localstorage with a different key/value

Tags: javascript, jquery, clone, store

Here's a sample of my code:

```
<!doctype html>
  <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
    </head>

    <body>
      <div class="box not-selected" id="box1">
        <a href="#" id="clone_once1" class="favorite"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="box not-selected" id="box2">
        <a href="#" id="clone_once2" class="favorite"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="box" id="fav"></div>

      <script>

        $('#clone_once1').on('click', function(){

          // Clone div
          var add = $(this).parent();
          add.each(function(){
            var boxContent = ($(this).clone(true).addClass('selected').removeClass('not-selected'));
            var get = $('#fav').append($(boxContent)).html();

            localStorage.setItem('clicked1', get);

            // Append item if localstorage is detected = Box1 Clone
            if (localStorage["clicked1"]) {
              $("#fav").append(localStorage["clicked1"]);
            };
          });
        });

        $('#clone_once2').on('click', function(){
          var add_2 = $(this).parent();
          add_2.each(function(){
            var boxContent_2 = ($(this).clone(true).addClass('selected').removeClass('not-selected'));
            var get_2 = $('#fav').append($(boxContent_2)).html();

            localStorage.setItem('clicked2', get_2);

            // Append item if localstorage is detected = Box2 Clone
            if (localStorage["clicked2"]) {
              $("#fav").append(localStorage["clicked2"]);
            };
          });
        });

      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Let's say I click in the a tag within the #box1 and then in the #box2.

The first value is picked right (#box1.html), however when I click on the second one it picks the html of the previous div clicked and then adds the new one (#box1.html, #box2.html). So in the end, when I refresh the page I get 3 divs, which is something I don't want to see. I need only these two divs to show.

How to prevent from this to happen?

I'm quite new to js and I would appreciate any help on this matter.

Comment: What is the required behaviour? What exactly you are trying to get in the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are facing issue because you are appending content  to #fav and then putting those in local storage, In below code on every click i have made #fav empty, So now every time you add anything old content will get removed.

```
   $('#clone_once1').on('click', function(){

      // Clone div
     // var objTemp = $('#fav').html("");//change
      var add = $(this).parent();
      add.each(function(){
        var boxContent = ($(this).clone(true).addClass('selected').removeClass('not-selected'));

        //var get = $('#fav').append($(boxContent)).html();
        var get = $(boxContent).html().trim();
        //if(localStorage.getItem('clicked1').length)
        var temp = localStorage.getItem('clicked1');
        if(temp==null)
        {
            var tempArray = [];
            tempArray[0] = get;
            localStorage.setItem('clicked1', JSON.stringify(tempArray));
        }else{
            var tempArray = JSON.parse(temp);
            tempArray.push(get);                
            localStorage.setItem('clicked1', JSON.stringify(tempArray));
        }

        // Append item if localstorage is detected = Box1 Clone
        if (localStorage["clicked1"]) {
            var tempHtml = "";
            $.each(JSON.parse(localStorage["clicked1"]),function(i){
                tempHtml += '<div class="box not-selected" id="box2">'+JSON.parse(localStorage["clicked1"])[i]+'</div>';
            }
            );
            //$("#fav").html("");
            $("#fav").append(tempHtml);
        };
      });
    });

    $("#clone_once2").on('click', function(){
    //$('#fav').html("");//change
      var add_2 = $(this).parent();
      add_2.each(function(){
        var boxContent_2 = ($(this).clone(true).addClass('selected').removeClass('not-selected'));

        //var get_2 = $('#fav').append($(boxContent_2)).html();
        var get_2 = $(boxContent_2).html().trim();
        //localStorage.setItem('clicked2', get_2);
        var temp = localStorage.getItem('clicked2');
        if(temp==null)
        {
            var tempArray = [];
            tempArray[0] = get_2;
            localStorage.setItem('clicked2', JSON.stringify(tempArray));
        }else{
            var tempArray = JSON.parse(temp);
            tempArray.push(get_2);              
             localStorage.setItem('clicked2', JSON.stringify(tempArray));
        }

        // Append item if localstorage is detected = Box2 Clone
        if (localStorage["clicked2"]) {
            var tempHtml = "";
            $.each(JSON.parse(localStorage["clicked2"]),function(i){
                tempHtml += '<div class="box not-selected" id="box2">'+JSON.parse(localStorage["clicked2"])[i]+'</div>';
            }
            );
        //$("#fav").html("");
        $("#fav").append(tempHtml);
        };
      });
    });
```

Comment: There's only one issue now. Only one div gets appended to the #fav div, even if I target both of them. When I refresh the page I get two divs, which is right.

Comment: What do you mean by target both of them, please provide clear requirement

Comment: Hi, sorry if I didn’t explain myself well. So, I want to create these clones (divs) and append them to a new tab (#fav) and then save these in local storage. As I said before, local storage is working perfectly and I think the fact that every click makes #fav empty it erases every clone ever created before, showing only the latest one I clicked on.. however I need to show all of them. Let me know if you understand the issue correctly.

Comment: As per my understanding of the requirement i have now updated your code. You will see all the clones added, But in local storage you will only see the elements added. If still not as per your requirement then kindly update your question with example.  Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply, much better now. Is there a way of getting rid of all the backwards slashes that get appended to localstorage? Because at the end the html gets broken after being stringified.

Comment: Yes we can do that ,you can write JavaScript to remove that.  If this has helped please mark is as an answer

Comment: I would appreciate if you could update the code with this last one thing. Many thanks!

Comment: Why do u want this backslashes to get removed? If this is not creating any issue.

Comment: It is, as I said before with the fact that it's creating slashes everywhere in the html, the output is not what I expected. So instead of seeing the div I clicked on.. in the new tab (#fav) after I refresh the page I can only see a bunch of words and slashes. What I see: http://imgur.com/a/wqID5 | What I should see: http://imgur.com/a/3EsRV

Comment: It still has all slashes.

Comment: i cant believe this, Please clear the cache and try, may be old data from your local storage is getting populated.,